# On a cisco device, how do you show the capabilities?

Tags: cisco

On a cisco device, you can run show cdp neighbors detail, and for each neighbour, you will see a line showing the capabilities, e.g.:

```
Platform: cisco WS-C6509-E,  Capabilities: Router Switch IGMP
```

How can you see this for the device you are currently on? show version has the platform, but not the capabilities.

Comment: Don't know of a way from the device itself, but you could packet capture out of a port on the switch with CDP enabled, and look at the packet...or go to the other switch and do a sh cdp neigh.  While these work, they don't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

This list of capabilities is really kind of bogus. It really just identifies whether it's a layer 2 device, layer 3 device, etc. If you're logged in, you should know what the device can do. Instead you might need to find out what features are supported, in which case you'd use a combination of the model and IOS verson with the cisco feature navigator tool: http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/jsp/index.jsp